# How to Convert a Multiple Array to Json Array and add Jsons to a hashmap

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I want to convert this Json String to an Array.
My hashmap named "HASHMRM"
this is my Json String:

```
[
    {"id":1,"name":"hamid"},
    {"id":2,"name":"mohamad"},
    {"id":3,"name":"ali"},
    {"id":4,"name":"john"},
    {"id":5,"name":"smith"}
]
```

and I wanna to convert this Json String To an Array like this

```
String myJsonstring ="[{"id":1,"name":"hamid"},{"id":2,"name":"mohamad"},{"id":3,"name":"ali"},{"id":4,"name":"john"},{"id":5,"name":"smith"}]";
string[] AA = Jsons.....

int i =0;
while(i<string.lenght)
{
    HASHMRM.put(AA[i].split()//First, AA[i].split()//second);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

First, you need POJO class that matches your data.

```
class MyUser {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

Then, convert your string to List of POJO class.

```
// This is your string.
String myJsonString = "[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"hamid\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"mohamad\"},{\"id\":3,\"name\":\"ali\"},{\"id\":4,\"name\":\"john\"},{\"id\":5,\"name\":\"smith\"}]";

// Create new Gson object.
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Convert
List<MyUser> userList = gson.fromJson(myJsonString, new TypeToken<List<MyUser>>() {
    }.getType());
```

Next, use it!

```
for (MyUser u : userList) {
    HASHMRM.put(u.id, u.name);
}
```

Remember: Instead of using the `HASHMRM` as variable name, I suggest you to use java conventional camel case name `HashMRM`.